# simple unique STL container

Tags: c++, stl

Is there a unique container such like `std::list` with simple functionality (`push`,`pop`,`clear`, etc.) and not sorted order unlike `std::set`, or maybe I need to extend  `std::list` and add my own `push_unique` method )) ?

Comment: You are perhaps looking for `std::(tr1::)unordered_set`.

Comment: Do you want the order of insertion to remain unchanged?

Comment: Do you need the container to retain the order of items pushed onto it?

Comment: Order doesn't matter, thanks Zack I will try

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The STL is supposed to provide *efficient* containers.

A container which does not allow duplicates needs to support fast lookup to determine whether the value you want to is already present in the collection or not.

`std::set` keeps the item sorted in a red-black tree, which is what allows an O(log(n)) lookup, insertion, and removal.

`std::unsorted_set` allows constant-time lookup, insertion, and removal, but you need to provide a hash function for most UDT types, you need to take care of issues such as rehashing, which cause iterator invalidation, and you do not have any defined order for your items (not even the insertion order).

If you want to use a simple collection such as `std::vector` without allowing duplicates, you need to provide your own adapter.

However, I still can't figure out why you have problems with a sorted container such as `std::set` if, as you say, the order doesn't matter for you.